# jQuery what is .drag? Dragging multiple elements at the same time not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm looking at this fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ubEqb/

You can see that dragging multiple elements at the same time works here. In this example, it has "$('.drag').drag("init", function(ev, dd)"

What is the '.drag' part? I am new to jquery and thought it was 'draggable', and I can't find any official documentation that '.drag' actually does anything.

If I copy the text from this fiddle into my html, it doesn't work. Here's what I got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
.drag {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #89B;
    background: #BCE;
    height: 58px;
    width: 58px;
    cursor: move;
    top: 120px;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/286533/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/286533/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Click to select multiple boxes, and drag them around the screen.</p>
    <div id="test" class="drag" style="left:20px;">Square 1</div>
    <div class="drag" style="left:100px;"></div>
    <div class="drag" style="left:180px;"></div>
</body>
<script>    
$('.drag').drag("init", function(ev, dd) {
    if (this.id == "test") {
        return $(".drag").addClass("selected");
    }
}).drag(function(ev, dd) {
    if (ev.target.id == "test") {
        $(this).css({
            top: dd.offsetY,
            left: dd.offsetX
        });
    }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "drag" method in jQuery or "drag" widget in jQuery UI. The "draggable" you are referring to is indeed part of jQuery UI. You can read about about it [here](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/).

What you are looking at in the jsfiddle is jQuery and some other third party library. If you take a look at the "External Resources" panel on the left you'll see there's one reference to a certain `jquery.event.drag-2.2.js` which is actually what defines the "drag" method in the jsfiddle.